# ReactJS print HTML comment

Tags: reactjs

To verify my site (universal reactjs application), I need to add an HTML comment with a verification code to the head of my document. I tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML on a meta tag and the react-jsx-html-comments library, but both seem to fail.

```
<meta name="verification" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<!-- 3215465 -->'}} />
```

I include the following in my server.js

```
res.send(`<!doctype html>${ReactDOM.renderToString(<Html assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} store={store} />)}`);
```

And the Html component looks like this:

```
export default class Html extends Component {
   static propTypes = {
    assets: PropTypes.object,
    component: PropTypes.node,
    store: PropTypes.object
  };

  render() {
    const { assets, component, store } = this.props;
    const content = component ? renderToString(component) : '';

    return (
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- CODE HERE -->
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}/>
      </body>
    );
}
```

EDIT: required output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- 64654654 -->
    </head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Is there another way of adding html comments? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `meta` is void element and can not have children elements., could you show what do you want to achieve? could you post HTML version?

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do `<head dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:"<!-- 123456 -->"}} />`

Comment: There are multiple meta/link/... statements in the head, so this would be a mess. This would work if it was only for the comment though.